# Setting a pointer to Parse with Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a user search for a school and then tap on the one they want. In cellForRowAtIndexPath I query for the school that was selected and get its objectId. I then set the objectId to the pointer, "school_name" in within PFUser.currentUser. The pointer goes to the "Schools" class where all of the schools are listed. I am getting an error that says, "invalid type for key school_name, expected *Schools, but got string (Code: 111, Version: 1.12.0)". I can't seem to get around it as the objectId is a string. I can even print the objectId getting the right one.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    let spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    spinningActivity.labelText = "Just a Moment"
    spinningActivity.detailsLabelText = "Adding Details"

    let schoolIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(schoolIndexPath)! as UITableViewCell
    let school : String = String(selectedCell.textLabel!.text!)

    let schoolObjectIdQuery = PFQuery(className:"Schools")
    schoolObjectIdQuery.whereKey("school_name", matchesRegex: school)



    let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([schoolObjectIdQuery])

    if reachabilityStatus == kNOTREACHABLE {

        spinningActivity.hide(true)



        self.displayAlert("No Internet Connection", message: "Please connect to the internet before continuing.")


    } else {

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil {

                self.displayAlert("Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)

            }

            if let objects = results {

                self.searchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                for object in objects {

                    let schoolObjectId = object.objectId!

                    let addDetails : PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()!

//                        let schoolObjectIdFormatted = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "school_name", objectId: schoolObjectId)

                    addDetails.setObject(schoolObjectId, forKey: "school_name")

                    print(school)
                    print(schoolObjectId)

                    addDetails.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in



                        if error != nil {

                            spinningActivity.hide(true)

                            self.displayAlert("Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)

                        }

                        if success {

                            spinningActivity.hide(true)

                            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

                            print("Success")

                        }

                    })



                }



            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to use a pointer... Not a string. Instead of saving the objectId you need to be saving the entire school object.

Comment: If I copy the objectId from the Schools class to the _User class, the pointer works fine. In this case, I just want to programmatically add the objectId. What exactly are you saying?

Comment: If you don't want to save a pointer and would rather just save the objectId then you need to change the column in your database from a pointer to a string. If you want the pointer, then instead of saving the objectId you need to save the whole school object. You may be able to do it from the data browser because it's smart enough to search all the objects and find a matching ID, but the SDK can't do that.

Comment: What I was trying to do was to save space on my server by having the school names show up in the class "School" and have each user get a pointer to that school rather than each user have the school listed in both "Schools" and "_User", but it sounds like that isn't the best option programmatically. Is there a better way to do it or am I best off having the String listed twice and not having a lot of queries being sent out when the app goes live?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is much more wrong with your code. Why do you have in your `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` a saveInBackGround for each downloaded object.

**If you want to store pointer, the syntax is this way**

```
addDetails["school_id"] = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "School", objectId: "\(schoolObjectId)")
```

school_id is a column name in Parse DB that is a type Pointer to the class School